# Stacked bar chart. Create one integrated Tooltip with information from all categories (Altair)

Tags: python, pandas, altair

Currently, the tooltip in my chart is separate for each 'stack'/category of the bar.

I would like to create an uniform tooltip that displays the same integrated information from all categories anywhere on the same bar.
For example:

- Date (year): 2020
- Count (total): 2
- Count 'true': 1
- Count 'false': 1
- % 'true': 50%

Would this be possible in Altair?
Below the code and output I have now.

```py
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['20-03-2017', '20-03-2017', '20-03-2018', '21-03-2018', '20-10-2019', '20-03-2019', '1-02-2019', '10-03-2020', '20-06-2020'],
    'value': [True, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False]
})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    x = 'year(date):O',
    y = 'count(value)',
    color = 'value',
    tooltip = ['year(date)', 'count(value)']
)
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not any super clean way to do this, because the tooltip for a given mark (e.g. the orange part of one of the bars) can only include values actually associated with that mark.

So to get the behavior that you want, you'll have to use [transforms](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/index.html) to compute those aggregated values and join them with the original dataset, so they are accessible to the tooltip for the desired marks. Here's an example:

```
alt.Chart(df).transform_timeunit(
    year='year(date)'
).transform_joinaggregate(
    count='count(value)',
    count_true='sum(value)',
    groupby=['year']
).transform_calculate(
    count_false = "datum.count - datum.count_true"
).mark_bar(opacity=1).encode(
    x='year(date):O',
    y='count():Q',
    color='value',
    tooltip=['year(date):O', 'count:Q', 'count_true:Q', 'count_false:Q']
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer Jake! For now, I decided to keep it more simple.

Comment: I noticed the question behind my question was, that it’s not intuitive to know the count only applies to one segment of the bar. So I updated the tooltip as follows: “tooltip = ['year(date)', ‘value’, 'count(value)']”. Now that is very clear and explicit.